# Plot over outer geometry representation

Tags: paraview

I am trying to get a plot of the pressure over the outer geometry line.

What I already tried in Paraview is the following:

1. ExtractSurface on patches/geometry
2. Slice e.g. on symmetry plane (y=0)
3. Clip z=const to get top and bottom region of geometry
4. Calculator coordsZ saved in new variable "Z"
5. Transform with scale (1,1,0) to shrink from 2D to 1D representation
6. PlotOverLine with high resolution and Points(0) for x-data and "Z" for y-data

The main problem are the overlapping lines. I just care about the outer geometry, in the attached example the max value of z. On that "surface-line" I want to plot e.g. the pressure. How to get the desired plot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution:

1. Using the Programmable Filter, you can write a script that produces a vtkTable which has 2 columns `x-data`, and `z-data`.
2. In this filter, you can iterate over all points in the input dataset and discard any points duplicate `x`, picking the ones with maximum z.
3. Now simply show the output of this filter in the `Line Chart View`.

If you are not familiar with writing scripts for the Programmable Filter, refer to the [ParaView Guide](http://www.paraview.org/paraview-guide/) or point me to the dataset and I can write you a working script.

Comment: Thx for the idea, I've never used ProgrammableFilters and had no idea it is there. Tough to get into it though. Can you expand your answer a bit, please? You don't need my input data (it's a tutorial from openfoam), you could just use any kind of geometry.